# Should an inner component share the Context with its containing component?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I presently have:

```
<EditForm EditContext="EditContext"
          OnValidSubmit="HandleValidSubmitAsync"
          OnInvalidSubmit="HandleInvalidSubmitAsync"
          Context="formContext">

        <AddressForm @ref="_addressElement"
                     Value="Model.AddressModel"
                     Context="@EditContext"
                     ReadOnly="@(ModeState == Mode.Read)"
                     OnValidated="OnAddressValidated"
                     ValueChanged="@OnAddressChanged" />
</EditForm>
```

There's a problem with the above. Because it shares, then in AddressForm when I do the following:

```
Context.OnFieldChanged += OnFieldChanged;
```

To be honest, I don't remember why I did this. And I don't need it in the `<AddressForm>` component. But I'm wondering if I was told there's a good reason to do this and so added this.

Is sharing the Context a good thing? Bad thing? Either way?

Comment: It is a Cascading Value you don't have to pass it like this. https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web/Forms/EditForm.cs,153

Comment: And capture the cascade it in the same way as `InputBase` - https://source.dot.net/#Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web/Forms/InputBase.cs,29

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Ok, so definitely going about this wrong to start. But more basic question, should I be working off that cascaded Context? Or should I declare my own for my component. With the key issue being I want that OnFieldChanged to be called only when a field in my AddressForm component changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you have something like this:

```cs
class Member
{
   public string FirstName
   public string LastName
   public AddressModel Addreess
   ...
}
```

```cs
class AddressModel
{
   public string Town
   ....
}
```

If so then the issue is that `EditContext` basically works on a flat single layer model.  It represents model fields with the `FieldIndentifier` readonly struct

```cs
public object Model
public string FieldName
```

The `Model` should be the `EditContext` model.  Here are some suggestions.

How you deal with this is design and data pipeline specific.  Here are some suggestions.

1. Split out how you edit bits of you data - modal dialog form for the address with it's own edit context and validation model which gets validated (and save decision made) in the modal dialog form.  You then update the main model by marking the field has changed if it has.
2. Flatten your model by building a `ModelEditContext` class with it's own validation model.  Saving then writes the data back to the complex object before saving back though the data pipeline.
3. Use Aggregate objects that do the above and more.  Too big a topic to cover here.

Comment: I think I'm going to treat the AddressModel as a black box component where it has a Value and ValueChanged public methods but has its own Context and it does not use/touch the Context of the containing component. What I have right now is half & half and that's definitely not good. thanks